# Why system doesn’t delete all installation files of an app which is uninstalled on WP8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I noticed that some apps, particularly to the online game, which their assets files often retained even if you have uninstalled it. In more detail, ordinarily, an app was installed to c:\Data\Programs{Application Id}\Install\, if you uninstalled the app, then the installation folder (c:\Data\Programs{Application ID}) will be removed also by system. But for some online game, even if you removed the app, the system still reserve some files or folders, e.g. c:\Data\Programs{Application Id}\Install\Assets\, and it just deleted the .DLL files, Manifest files and some others, not all of them. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the detected path to：c:\Data\Programs{Application Id}\TempInstall\, it solved my problem.